# Change the color of .icon-bar to white?

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the color of a collapsed menu icon-bar to white (the three stacked lines on mobile devices).  I just can't seem to figure it out.

Here's my html:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-left newstyle" href="http://hopewellmc.org"><img height="50" alt="Brand" src="http://hopewellmc.org/favicons/Badge.png"></a>
    </div>
```

I've tried changing the CSS file but I can't seem to find the right style to change those bars to white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/pu6gqo48/

I guess you are using bootstrap 3, so what you need to do is to add 2 selectors for the `icon-bar` class.

```
.navbar-header .navbar-toggle.collapsed .icon-bar {
  background-color: gray;
}

.navbar-header .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: white;
}
```

The example uses blue and red colors.

Comment: Yes, I am using Boostrap 3.  Unfortunately that didn't work.  I wonder if there is something in the CSS that is overriding the color?  My html starts with "navbar-header" not "navbar-default"  does that make any difference?  Thanks for the help and sorry for the dumb question as I'm new to this.

Comment: 2 solutions. use `!important` at your specific styles (not recommended though) or check the sequence of the styles loaded.

Comment: you dont have a `navbar-default` as parent element above navbar-header?

Comment: updated my answer with new selectors. sorry i thought you used the commonly used navbar elements and styles so i used the `navbar-default`. it also works with `navbar-header` too.

Comment: Thank you!  That worked.  I am using a WYSIWYG website builder and the html in the OP is what was generated.  I'm not sure why 'navbar-default' wasn't used.

Answer (score 0):

I added to class navbar-dark and my hamburger become with white lines

```
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right navbar-dark lined" type="button" data- 
        toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" 
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" 
        aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>      
 </button>
```